# Calculating percentage error from R-squared error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I created a ML model with Scikit Learn and Python. I calculated R-Squared error. Is there a way to convert this error to percentage error?
For example, If my true values are 100 and 50, and predicted values are 90 and 40, my average percentage error is 15%, because error for first prediction is 10% and error for second prediction is 20%.
Is there a way to calculate percentage error *(average percentage error) based on the value that I get for R-squared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. The R-squared is calculated via [RSS, or residual sum of squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares). Your r-squared is 1 - (RSS in model)/(RSS in intercept only model). From the above, you can see that R-squared is not really an error per se, but the percentage of variance explained.

We can use an example dataset

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
```

We let the prediction and mean of y be:

```
ybar = reg.predict(X)
ymean = y.mean()
```

The R-squared is

```
1 - sum((y-ybar)**2) / sum((y-ymean)**2)
0.7406426641094095

reg.score(X, y)
0.7406426641094095
```

Whereas your percentage error is:

```
np.mean(abs(y-ybar)/y)
0.16417298806489977
```

As you can see, it is not quite possible to just get back the mean percentage error from Rsq because you have already summed up the residuals and in the percentage error, you need the error relative to the observation

Answer (score 2):

From your question, it sounds like you're working with a **regression** model. I would recommend looking into [sklearn's built-in regression accuracy methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics) instead of trying to use R^2, which, is too an accuracy metric. For what you are trying to do, I would probably recommend trying out the mean_absolute_error or median_absolute_error- but other accuracy metrics can be useful in tuning your model!

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.metrics import median_absolute_error
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
MAE = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
MEDAE = median_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
```

If you're building a **classifier** should be able to use [sklearn's accuracy_score metric](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html). This will divide the number of correct predictions by the total number of predictions. Multiplying this number by 100 will yield the percentage of correct predictions. To get the percent of incorrect predictions you can just use `100(1-accuracy_score)`.

Answer (score -1):

The above answer seems adequate but I've felt a confusion in the question so I'm leaving this right here.
R-squared is a metric that answers the question "If I were to use the average of target, would it be better than my predictions?", and gives you the value where if your model is worst than the baseline (average of target) gives you below zero, and if your model is better than the baseline, gives you something close to one. It is stated before but there are guidelines regarding which error you should use. If you're a starter I would suggest you to use mean squared error, as in the end you will get "the slope and the intercept where the mean squared error is zero" (some fancy differentiations take place there). In MSE, the distance between the data points and your model's predictions get squared, every squared distance (error) is summed up and then it takes the mean of the summed errors. Therefore, there's no way you can calculate error from R-squared, as they're not really related. You can implement MSE within the sklearn documentation like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
```

For other metrics in the sklearn (including classification and clustering metrics), see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html). Sklearn's documentation is even better than the tutorials online.
You can also simply type `sklearn.metrics.SCORERS.keys()` to see the available metrics in the sklearn.